# Use Entity Framework 4.1 with SQLITE

Tags: .net, entity-framework, sqlite, entity-framework-4.1

Is is possible? I have an existing database, and created entity classes:

```
public class MyContainer : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Item> Items { get; set; }
    // more tables..
}
```

When I use this connection string it fails since it do not have any meta data files:

```
  <connectionStrings>    
  <add name="MyContainer" 
         connectionString="metadata=.\items.csdl|.\items.ssdl|.\items.msl;provider=System.Data.SQLite;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.\mindstore.sqlite.s3db&quot;" 
         providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

But when I omit the metadata from the config it complains that you are not allowed to omit the meta data from the config.

So how is it possible to use SQLITE together with EF 4.1 without any xml configuration files and just doing mapping per convention?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use EF code first without EDMX you can't use `EntityClient`. Use common ADO.NET connection string for SQLite:

```
<connectionStrings>    
    <add name="MyContainer" providerName="System.Data.SQLite"
         connectionString="data source=.\mindstore.sqlite.s3db" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Edit:

To turn off database creation and database checks try removing default metadata convention and setting database initializer to null.

Database initializer:

```
// call this only once in your application bootstrap
Database.SetInitializer<YourContext>(null);
```

Removing the convention:

```
// Place this to your derived context
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) 
{
    base.OnModelCreationg(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<IncludeMetadataConvention>();
}
```

Comment: Now it tells me "DatabaseExists is not supported by the provider."

Comment: Now you have a problem because your provider doesn't support all necessary functionality used by EF code first. Either check if there is newer version of the provider or try to turn off all EF features related to database creation (you will have to create database and tables yourselves).

Comment: The database already exists, so this is no problem. How can I turn off these features which fail here?

Comment: The answer should clarify what "EDMX" is.  Also why is it significant that you can't use EntityClient.

Comment: @Lee: Why? The answer explains current problem. It is not supposed to be documentation to entity framework. Moreover anybody who knows difference between code first and not code first knows what EDMX is. That is one of the very first information you will find if you start to use entity framework.

Comment: @Ladislav: I can prove you wrong on this because I know the former but not the latter: *Moreover anybody who knows difference between code first and not code first knows what EDMX is.*

The reason is because I haven't used EF on a project yet, but I've been following it's progress on ScottGu's blog so I know what code first offers.  I came here to research a couple points before starting.

Philosophically, I think if the answer introduces a new acronym that wasn't part of the original question, it should be linked or parened like this EDMX (EF XML file format).